# find element in list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df1":

```
adj           response

beautiful    ["She's a beautiful girl/woman, and also a good teacher."]
good         ["She's a beautiful girl/woman, and also a good teacher."]
hideous      ["This city is hideous, let's move to the countryside."]
```

And here's the object list:

```
object=["girl","teacher","city","countryside","woman"]
```

Code:

```
df1['response_split']=df1['response'].str.split(",")
```

After I split it, the dataframe will be like this:

```
adj           response_split

beautiful    ["She's a beautiful girl/woman", " and also a good teacher."]
good         ["She's a beautiful girl/woman", " and also a good teacher."]
hideous      ["This city is hideous", " let's move to the countryside."]
```

I want to add another column "response_object", if they find the adj in response, they find its object from list object: **expected result**

```
adj           response_split                                               response_object

beautiful    ["She's a beautiful girl/woman", " and also a good teacher."]        girl
beautiful    ["She's a beautiful girl/woman", " and also a good teacher."]        woman
good         ["She's a beautiful girl/woman", " and also a good teacher."]        teacher
hideous      ["This city is hideous", " let's move to the countryside."]          city
```

code:

```
for i in df1['response_split']:
    if df1['adj'] in i:
        if any(x in i and x in object):
            match = list(filter(lambda x: x in i, object))
            df1['response_object']=match
```

It prints **ValueError**

Comment: can you provide the full error

Comment: @AnkushRasgon ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `object` is valid python `builtins` (code word), so better dont use it for variable, here is changed to `L`:

```
L=["girl","teacher","city","countryside","woman"]
```

Then `zip` splitted column with `adj`, loop by tuples, loop by values in `L` and match if both match with `in` and `and`:

```
df1['response_split']=df1['response'].str.split(",")
L1 = [(a, b, o) for a, b in zip(df1['adj'], df1['response_split']) 
                for r in b 
                for o in L 
                if (o in r) and (a in r)]
```

What should be rewrite to loops:

```
df1['response_split']=df1['response'].str.split(",")

L1 = []
for a, b in zip(df1['adj'], df1['response_split']):
    for r in b:
        for o in L:
            if (o in r) and (a in r):
                L1.append((a, b, o))
```

Last create `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(L1, columns=['adj','response_split','response_object'])
print (df2)
         adj                                     response_split  \
0  beautiful  [She's a beautiful girl/woman,  and also a goo...   
1  beautiful  [She's a beautiful girl/woman,  and also a goo...   
2       good  [She's a beautiful girl/woman,  and also a goo...   
3    hideous  [This city is hideous,  let's move to the coun...   

  response_object  
0            girl  
1           woman  
2         teacher  
3            city
```